# How to apply css in Sencha? I am using Sencha architect 3

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

All the search results are showing how to do it in sencha architect 2 not in sencha architect 3.

Answer (score 0):

Add a css resource from the toolbox.  http://docs.sencha.com/architect/3/#!/guide/resources